# How to make and, or, not, xor, plus using only substraction

Tags: math, logic

I read that there is a computer that uses only subtraction.
How is that possible. For the plus operand it's pretty easy.
The logical operands I think can be made using subtraction with a constant.

What do you guys think ?

Comment: `What do you guys think?` - we think, this question is better suited for [Mathematica](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/) hub, not SO...

Comment: Logical operands don't belong on Mathematica, IMO.

Comment: @Teepeemm, ouch >_< Yeah, sorry, better to look into [boolean-algebra](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/boolean-algebra) tag on [Mathematics](http://math.stackexchange.com/) hub

Answer (score 2):

1. **Plus `+`**

   is easy as you already have `minus` implemented so:

   - `x + y = x - (0-y)`
2. **NOT `!`**

   In standard **ALU** is usual to compute substraction by addition:

   - `-x = !x + 1`

   So from this the negation is:

   - `!x = -1 - x`
3. **AND `&`,OR `|`,XOR `^`**

   Sorry have no clue about efficient `AND,OR,XOR` implementations without more info about the architecture other then testing each bit individually  from **MSB** to **LSB**. So first you need to know the bit value from a number so let assume **4 bit unsigned integer** numbers for simplification so `x=(x3,x2,x1,x0)` where `x3` is the **MSB** and `x0` is the **LSB**.

   ```
   if (x>=8) { x3=1; x-=8; } else x3=0;
   if (x>=4) { x2=1; x-=4; } else x2=0;
   if (x>=2) { x1=1; x-=2; } else x1=0;
   if (x>=1) { x0=1; x-=1; } else x0=0;
   ```

   And this is how to get the number back

   ```
   x=0
   if (x0) x+=1;
   if (x1) x+=2;
   if (x2) x+=4;
   if (x3) x+=8;
   ```

   or like this:

   ```
   x=15
   if (!x0) x-=1;
   if (!x1) x-=2;
   if (!x2) x-=4;
   if (!x3) x-=8;
   ```

   now we can do the **AND,OR,XOR** operations

   ```
   z=x&y // AND
   z0=(x0+y0==2);
   z1=(x1+y1==2);
   z2=(x2+y2==2);
   z3=(x3+y3==2);

   z=x|y // OR
   z0=(x0+y0>0);
   z1=(x1+y1>0);
   z2=(x2+y2>0);
   z3=(x3+y3>0);

   z=x^y // XOR
   z0=!(x0+y0==1);
   z1=!(x1+y1==1);
   z2=!(x2+y2==1);
   z3=!(x3+y3==1);
   ```

   **PS** the comparison is just substraction + **Carry** and **Zero** flags examination. Also all the `+` can be rewriten and optimized to use of `-` to better suite this weird architecture
4. **bit shift `<<,>>`**

   ```
   z=x>>1
   z0=x1;
   z1=x2;
   z2=x3;
   z3=0;

   z=x<<1
   z0=0;
   z1=x0;
   z2=x1;
   z3=x2;
   ```